# I can't get my paypal dropdown to center in the div

Tags: html, css

If you go to this page http://www.mikarate.com and scroll down about 75% you'll see a box called Membership giving a new member choices using a dropdown.

I have tried everything to get dropdown to center inside it's div block. I've put `margin: 0 auto` and `text-align: center` everywhere I can think of and nothing seems to work. So frustrating... So I finally gave up and just added `padding: 0.625em 0.625em 0.625em 8.125em;` So now of course when viewed on mobile the dropdown is too far right or left depending on the device.

Can anyone give me a hand here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding from your `<table>` and apply the following rules to `<tbody>` and your `<select>` will appear centered...

```
tbody {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

ps -  you shouldn't need to use a `<table>` for this. Just throw your `<select>` in there with a `<label for="">` and be done with it

Comment: @GregRobertson great! please accept the answer if you found this helpful and happy coding